# How to identify the reason of tensorflow network runs slow and run out of memory

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, conv-neural-network

I am doing a research on multibranched network vs. non-branched network, I am using the UNET as example. The input is an normal image of dimension(256,256,3)and the output is the a set of images concatenated togethor with dimension(256,256,9).

In my experiment, I used traditional UNET with single conv layer, the network works fine.

Since the network would output a set of images, I used multi branches of network for each image: one of the network looks like this: https://i.stack.imgur.com/RNsIw.png

I adjusted the dimensions of the convolution and FC(dense) layers so that all network has similar trainable parameters(to ensure a similar complexity level of model). However, the speed of the branched version is much slower than the original. Also, the more branches it has, the slower it computes. I would like to know which part should I look into to find what makes the branched network running slowly.

Secondly, for some branched version, tensorflow warned me that I have run out of memory. I wonder what exactly determines the amount of memory needed for tensorflow.

All network use identical data loader and loss function.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: It is absolutely expected that the branched version will be slower than the non-branched version because the branched version relies on inter ops parallelism while the non-branched one relies on intra ops parallelism and inter ops parallelism is (much) slower. That means even if you didn't make any mistakes, branched one should be slower. But if you suspect that anything can be further optimized, you may have to provide more codes.

Comment: @LaplaceRicky Thank you so much it is very helpful, I dont have to optimise it. however, I wonder if I tried to optimise it, theoretically, would the branched version be at same speed as non-branched one?

Comment: If you are using tensorflow API, then no, branched version will always be slower.